# Is validation set essential in machine learning research paper?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, data-science, training-data

I know that validation set is very import since in brief we can check our model and tune optimal hyperparameters without handling the test set. However, **there are some papers about machine learning that had not made validation set**. For example, in [Neural Collaborative Filtering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05031) authors mentioned that they use validation set to tune hyperparameters, but on provided [code](https://github.com/hexiangnan/neural_collaborative_filtering/blob/master/GMF.py#L160) they just trained a model with train set and validated it with **test set** for each epoch.

```
for epoch in xrange(epochs):
    t1 = time()
    # Generate training instances
    user_input, item_input, labels = get_train_instances(train, num_negatives)

    # Training
    hist = model.fit([np.array(user_input), np.array(item_input)], #input
                     np.array(labels), # labels 
                     batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=1, verbose=0, shuffle=True)
    t2 = time()

    # Evaluation
    if epoch %verbose == 0:
        (hits, ndcgs) = evaluate_model(model, testRatings, testNegatives, topK, evaluation_threads)
        hr, ndcg, loss = np.array(hits).mean(), np.array(ndcgs).mean(), hist.history['loss'][0]
        print('Iteration %d [%.1f s]: HR = %.4f, NDCG = %.4f, loss = %.4f [%.1f s]' 
              % (epoch,  t2-t1, hr, ndcg, loss, time()-t2))
        if hr > best_hr:
            best_hr, best_ndcg, best_iter = hr, ndcg, epoch
            if args.out > 0:
                model.save_weights(model_out_file, overwrite=True)
```

I couldn't find any code of making or treating validation set in that github.
**Is it okay for just using test set instead of validation set for any kinds of machine learning research?** Meanwhile, in my opinion, we should use validation set for competitions like Kaggle or real-life system.